# Rmarkdown - evaluate or display the parametized query of an SQL chunk

Tags: sql, r, r-markdown, dbi

I am using parametized SQL queries in my Rmarkdown file, for safety as well as readibility reasons.

Eventually, I come with queries that include dynamic tables names, dynamic parameters, and even dynamic text (using logical evaluated variables), for example :
(dynamic variables may have been defined thanks to `glue_sql()`)

````r
```{sql, output.var = "data"}
select * from ?table_name 
where color = ?color_value 
?if_I_want_names and name in (?names_choices) 
limit ?limit_value
'``
````

In case of long and complex parametized query, it could be very useful (for checks and debugging) to access the fully-"evaluated" query. Expected result, in our example, would be:

> "select * from flowers\n 
>   where color = 'red' \n
>   -- and name in ('rose', 'tulip')\n 
>   limit 10"

or

```sql
select * from flowers 
where color = 'red' 
-- and name in ('rose', 'tulip') 
limit 10
```

But I have no idea how to do it... Playing with chunk parameters did not help. Any other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I came up with my own answer. I will post it here, might be useful someday for someone.

I simply re-used the interpolation function from the sql engine function from `knitr` (can be found [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/engine.R#LC492)) to define my function:

```r
require('DBI')
require('knitr')
require('glue')

# Return char vector of sql interpolation param names
varnames_from_sql = function(conn = ANSI(), sql) {
  varPos = DBI::sqlParseVariables(conn, sql)
  if (length(varPos$start) > 0) {
    varNames = substring(sql, varPos$start, varPos$end)
    sub('^\\?', '', varNames)
  }
}

# Vectorized version of exists
mexists = function(x, env = knit_global(), inherits = TRUE) {
  vapply(x, exists, logical(1), where = env, inherits = inherits)
}

# Interpolate a sql query based on the variables in an environment
interpolate_from_env = function(conn = ANSI(), sql, env = knit_global(), inherits = TRUE) {
  names = unique(varnames_from_sql(conn, sql))
  names_missing = names[!mexists(names, env, inherits)]
  if (length(names_missing) > 0) {
    stop("Object(s) not found: ", paste('"', names_missing, '"', collapse = ", "))
  }

  args = if (length(names) > 0) setNames(
    mget(names, envir = env, inherits = inherits), names
  )

  do.call(DBI::sqlInterpolate, c(list(conn, sql), args))
}
```

Then, I can call it my SQL expression to get the proper eval:

```r
interpolate_from_env(sql = "select * from ?table_name 
                            where color = ?color_value 
                            ?if_I_want_names and name in (?names_choices_sql)
                            limit ?limit_value")
```

which returns the expected result :

> select * from flowers
>                              where color = 'red'
>                              -- and name in ('rose', 'tulip')
>                              limit 10

**Note** :
this method will require a proper pre-evaluation of your variables using `glue_sql()`.
In this case :

```r
table_name <- glue_sql("flowers")
color_value <- "red"
names_choices <- 
names_choices_sql <- glue_sql("{c("rose", "tulip")*}", # the {}* allows to collapse a vector in SQL format 
                              .con = ANSI())
if_I_want_names <- glue_sql("--")
limit_value <- 10
```